# How to change display orientation from horizontal to vertical programmatically and rotate camera view accordingly?

Tags: python, camera, orientation, webcam, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a project where I need to dynamically change the display orientation from horizontal to vertical programmatically. The goal is to switch the display's view.

Additionally, I want to incorporate a camera feed into the application and ensure that the camera view is also rotated to match the display orientation. So, when the display is in vertical view, the camera feed should also be vertical.

Could someone please guide me on how to achieve both the display orientation change and the camera view rotation programmatically? Any help with code examples or references to relevant APIs and functions would be highly appreciated.